# rosnode kill doesn't kill a node

Tags: rosnode

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created a rosnode in C++.  It will not be killed by rosnode kill .

Can anyone tell me why this might this might be happening?

Thanks,
Paul.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11765/rosnode-kill-doesn%27t-kill-a-node/) by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 271 on 2011-11-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On the [rosnode page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosnode), it states that `rosnode kill` is not guaranteed to succeed. If your node is set to "respawn", `rosnode kill` won't kill it properly.  The other (more likely) cause of this problem is that your node is "hanging". What this means is that you're trapped in some infinite loop that does not check for the continued existence of ROS.

For example, instead of

```
while (1) {}
```

use

```
while (ros::ok()) {}
```

I've also run into problems with nodes hanging due to socket connections that fail to close properly.

In the case that you must shut down a node immediately, you can use the following command to kill it less nicely (provided that you're on a *Nix operating system):

```
kill $(ps aux | grep your_node | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
```

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on 2011-11-05**:
Thanks Dimitri!